# Efficient Component Management in React using Bit.dev

Tags: reactjs, react-native, monorepo, micro-frontend, bit.dev

Suppose I have a React project with the following structure involving *bit*: I have a *bit* folder at the project's root level. Inside this *bit* folder, I initialize *bit*, creating a bit ecosystem.

I'm wondering if it's considered a best practice to directly import components from the *bit* folder when they are needed, without installing them using yarn. This might involve using a tool like **Turbo Repo**. I'm facing difficulties with my current approach:

whenever I update a component in the *bit* folder, I need to perform a `bit tag` and `bit export` it. Subsequently, I must reinstall the component using yarn with the latest version from the *bit.cloud*. This process is cumbersome. Would it be more effective to import components directly from the *bit* folder, eliminating the need to consistently install the latest yarn version of the component in the project root?

I've already exported it to the scope, making it easily consumable for others. **My aim is to avoid the repetitive installation of components whenever their versions are updated in my React project.**

here is my project structure:

[my structure folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMP7w.png)

> if best practice, it's acceptable to add the 'bit' folder from a React project to the .gitignore file?